# Java thread join 3

Tags: java, multithreading

The program creates thread t0 which spawns thread t1 and subsequently threads t2 and t3 are created.After the execution of thread `t3`and the application never returns to the other threads spawned earlier(t0,t1,t2) and they are left stuck.

Why are the threads `t0`, `t1`, and `t2` suspended?

```
     public class Cult extends Thread 
            {  
                private String[] names = {"t1", "t2", "t3"};
                static int count = 0;
                public void run() 
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
                    {
                        if(i == 5 && count < 3) 
                        {
                            Thread t = new Cult(names[count++]);
                            t.start();
                            try{
                                Thread.currentThread().join();
                            }
                            catch(InterruptedException e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " ");
                    } 
                 }

                 public static void main(String[] a`)
                 {
                     new Cult("t0").start();
                 }
            }
```

Comment: You probably want `t.join()` not `Thread.currentThread().join();`

Comment: @Gray: That is exactly what I seek. t.join() executes properly with t3 finishing first and t0 finishing last.But what happens when we use Thread.currentThread.join()?Why t0,t1,t2 are suspended in the middle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important point you missed:

```
Thread.currentThread().join();
```

Method `join` in source code uses `isAlive` method.

```
public final synchronized void join(long millis) 
    ...
    if (millis == 0) {
        while (isAlive()) {
        wait(0);
        }
    ...
    }
```

It means that `Thread.currentThread().join()` will return only when `Thread.currentThread()` is dead.

But in your case it's impossible because of your running code in `Thread.currentThread()` has itself
this peace of code `Thread.currentThread().join()`. That's why after Thread 3 completion your program should hang and nothing happens thereafter.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Why are the threads t0, t1, and t2 suspended? The execution of thread t3 completes.

`t3` completes because it is *not* trying to fork a 4th thread and therefore is not trying to `join()` with it's own thread.  The following line will never return so t0, t1, and t2 all stop there and wait forever:

```
Thread.currentThread().join();
```

This is asking the current thread to wait for *itself* to finish which doesn't work.  I suspect that you meant to say `t.join();` which is waiting for the thread that was just forked to finish.

Here are some other thoughts about your code in no apparent order:

- You should consider `implements Runnable` instead of `extends Thread`.  See here: ["implements Runnable" vs. "extends Thread"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread)
- You are using the shared `static` variable `count` in multiple threads without any protection of locking.  The best solution is to use an `AtomicInteger` instead of a `int`.  You probably don't have a problem here because each thread is modifying `count` and then forking another thread but if you tried to fork 2 threads, this would be a real problem because of data race conditions.
- I'm not sure why you are only spawning another thread `if(i == 5 && count < 3)`.  `i` is only going to be `5` *once* in that loop.  Is that really what you intended?
- `String[] names = {"t1", "t2", "t3"};` fields are recommended to be declared at the *top* of classes.  Otherwise they get buried in the code and get lost.
- In `main` you start a `Cult` thread and then the main thread finishes.  This is unnecessary and you can just call `cult.run();` in `main` instead and use the main thread.
- `Cult(String s) { super(s); }` there is no point in having a constructor that calls the super constructor with the same arguments.  This can be removed.
- This is debatable but I tend to put `main` method at the top of the class and not bury it since it is the "entrance" method.  Same thing with constructors.  Those should be *above* the `run()` method.
- `catch(Exception e) {}` is a *really* bad pattern.  At the very least you should do a `e.printStackTrace();` or log it somehow.  Catching and just dropping exceptions hides a *lot* of problems.  Also, catching `Exception` should be changed to `catch(InterruptedException e)`.  You want to restrict your catch blocks *just* the exceptions thrown by the block otherwise this may again hide problems in the future if you copy and paste that block somewhere.
- More a good practice but never use constants like `3` that have to match another data item.  In this case it would be better to use `names.length` which is 3.  THis means that you don't need to change 2 places in the code if you want to increase the number of threads.  You could also have the name be `"t" + count` and get rid of the `names` array altogether.